# phpquery динамическая дозагрузка страницы

Tags: php, ajax, phpquery

Всем привет , столкнулся с проблемой не могу загрузить всю страницу c помощью `phpquery`, которая дозагружается `ajax` (загрузка по мере прокрутки страницы) , пробовал с помощью `cURL` но страница загружается до загрузки `ajax`, может кто посоветует рабочий вариант решения проблемы ?
пример кода (cURL использовал разные варианты )

```
function request($url){

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $data;
}

$doc= phpQuery::newDocument(request($url));
$doc-> .......
```

Comment: не получится у вас так сделать. Можете взять и самостоятельно обратиться к тем URL, которые запрашивает ajax, и оттуда взять данные.

Comment: да можно и так ,  но проблема в том что url меняются в нем передаются параметры, и мне такой вариант не подходит

Comment: а другого варианта у вас особо и нет.

Comment: есть варианты с COM-браузером под виндой, или прочими реализациями API-браузеров. но проще разобраться с ajax-запросами и их параметрами.

Comment: пришлось разобраться с ajax запросом , других решений не нашел, всем спасибо